# Hypothetical experimental design - help needed for statistical analysis

Tags: regression, experiment-design

I am proposing a hypothetical lab experiment where participants are randomly assigned into T(exposure to social norms messaging) and C (neutral messaging).

Each group is then subsequently asked their intent to reduce meat intake along the lines of “How interested are you in eating less meat in the future?” (1 = not at all, 5 = somewhat, 10 = extremely).

Can anyone help me understand how I would then go about measuring whether the 'intention score' increases with exposure to the norms messaging?

Comment: You could search this site for ordinal logistic and if what you find does not help edit your question to say why and how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would probably want to test the hypothesis that the outcome is different in these two groups.

Since the scale of the dependent variable is `ordinal`, you want to perform a Wilcoxon-Mann Whitney U-test.

[This page](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/whatstat/) describes how to perform these hypothesis tests in a few common statistical software packages.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much, this is very helpful. From what I've read, this would then allow me to compare the ranking of 'intent scores' (my d.v.) between Treatment and Control groups and see if the difference is statistically significant.

And with this test, from what I understand this means I don't need to 'assume' normality either.

Comment: this should probably be a comment to my answer and not an answer itself. And yes, that is the purpose of the test.